# How to get the extension of a file name using a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, file-extension

How do I get the extension of a file name using a SQL Server stored procedure?

I want to get the extension of the file name

For example, if the file name is `sdgfh_h670-ff.docx`, the result should be `.docx`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Server's built in string functions:

```
SELECT RIGHT('sdgfh_h670-ff.docx',CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE('sdgfh_h670-ff.docx')))
```